# Java util logging wrong format after overriding the formatter

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I want to change the format of the log but after I overrided the formatter, it still outputs in the old way.

```
private void initializeLogger() {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("gameLogger");
        try {
            Handler handler = new FileHandler("/home/bobby/IdeaProjects/GoFishBobby/src/logs/log1.txt");
            MyFormatter myFormatter = new MyFormatter();
            handler.setFormatter(myFormatter);
            logger.addHandler(handler);
            for (Handler parentHandler : logger.getParent().getHandlers())
                logger.removeHandler(parentHandler);

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO exception");
        }

        logger.info("Game starting : ");
    }
```

I overrided the default loggerFormatter

```
public class MyFormatter extends Formatter{
    public String format(LogRecord record){
        return record.getMessage();
    }
}
```

and the output still contains the info line with the information I dont need

```
SEVERE: NativePlayer : 0 Scored A Book of rank 3
Mar 05, 2017 1:15:44 PM Game logAfterPlay
INFO: The transfer hand is:
 4D 4H 4S
```

### Edit

I just found out the log in the file is correct, but why its still like this on the console? how do I get rid of it on the console. I already removed all the parent logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate all handlers by using the following method to walk all currently created loggers.

```
public static void printLoggerTree() {
    final LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    synchronized (manager) {
        final Enumeration<String> e = manager.getLoggerNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            final Logger l = manager.getLogger(e.nextElement());
            if (l != null) {
                for (Handler h : l.getHandlers()) {
                    System.out.println(l.getName() + "=" + h);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logger tree changes over time when different parts of your code requests new loggers.  So it matters when you call this method.

A better practice is to setup your own [logging.properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) file and configure your project to use that on startup.  You also don't need to create your own formatter as you can  [change the format pattern of the SimpleFormater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) on the command line by using the following:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%5$s%n"
```